# PowerAutomate : Get max columnvalue From dataverse table

Tags: odata, power-automate, dataverse

I have a **Dataverse** table named `my_sample_table`.

Inside the table I have a column named `my_sample_column` of type integer whose max value should be returned. Am trying to achieve this by using the **List rows** action provided with PowerAutomate.

[image]

Is there a filter query that can be written on the **Filter rows** property ? similar to what we use with SQL : `max(columnname)`

Or any other queries that can be included in the **List rows** action which will return the same result.

I know that I can iterate through the column values to get the max value using an expresion or by sorting it and getting the topmost one. But I was wondering whether there are any direct approach to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use a max aggregate for this column in a Fetch Xml query:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/use-fetchxml-aggregation#max

Comment: I tried this one, but it was giving me an error like "'my_sample_table' with namemapping = 'Logical' was not found in the MetadataCache". Am not sure whether some setting up is needed to be done at the table level for this to work?

Comment: The easiest way to write the fetch xml query is to use the advanced find and just export that xml. This article has the example steps of that: https://forwardforever.com/fetch-xml-the-hidden-gem-of-flow/